# jQuery .change() on Radio Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I must be missing something obvious here... I can't get [.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/) to fire on radio buttons? I have the code below live [here](http://bjmarine.net/test.html)!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Radio Button jQuery Change</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        console.log("parsed");
        $("input[name='rdio']").change(function() {
            console.log("changed");
            if ($("input[name='rdio']:checked").val() == 'a')
                $("output").text("a changed");
            else if ($("input[name='rdio']:checked").val() == 'b')
                $("output").text("b changed");
            else
                $("output").text("c changed");
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <input type="radio" name="rdio" value="a" checked="checked" /> a <br/>
        <input type="radio" name="rdio" value="b" /> b <br/>
        <input type="radio" name="rdio" value="c" /> c
    </div>
    <h3>Output:</h3>
    <div id="output"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone see what I've missed?

Thanks,
Denis

Comment: ... at least the `#` at `$("output")`...

Comment: you also can use this.value instead "input[name='rdio']:checked").val(). It will be more efficient.

Comment: Here is doc about `this` context https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You must put the code inside the dom-ready event...

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   // Your code here
 });
```

or else the script gets executed before the HTML-elements have been loaded. Thus, no radioboxes exist.

Answer (score 16):

Your

```
$("output").text("a changed");
```

should also be

```
$("#output").text("a changed");
```

because it is an id you are matching against.